# How to parameterize values in the csv file which is already parameterized in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, scripting, performance-testing

I have multiple API request bodies and Im passing them using txt file in CSV Data Set Config. This API request bodies have certain values to parameterize. How Do I acheive this? something like paramertize inside parameterized csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file contains [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which you want to evaluate in the runtime you need to wrap the variable(s) defined in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

For example if you have:

1. `test.csv` file with the single line containing `${foo}` and [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) reading this file into `some-variable`

   [image]
2. [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) which assigns the variable `foo` the value of `bar`

   [image]
3. And a couple of [Debug Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) for visualization

You will see that:

- `${some-variable}` will return `${foo}`, basically the line from the CSV file
- `${__eval(${some-variable})}` will return `bar` because the variable will be **eval**uated and its respective value will be resolved.

[image]